# Reshaping 1D numpy array which contain 2D data

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have come up with a numpy array which has dimension as (d1, ) when I execute `np.shape(a)`.

When I execute `np.shape(a[<any index within range>])`, it gives me (d2, d3) as output.

How can I convert it to (d1, d2, d3) upon executing `np.shape(a)`.

Comment: How did you get/create `a` in the first place?

Comment: It was a long process. I created vector representations of sentences within each document in the dataset with some processing and then accumulated everything together to get this array. In that process, somewhere I used list rather than numpy array. Thats the reason my 2nd dimension is of type list rather than numpy array. So, I just want to know whether there is any quick way to get 3d array. Otherwise, I have to make changes in the data processing step which is again a long process.

Comment: You can try `np.array(a.tolist())`, but I would definitely recommend reviewing your data processing.

Comment: hmm.. ok thanks.. will check it.